# Adding file autocompletion in rake with zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I have `oh-my-zsh` installed with the `rails` plugin, when I use `zsh` completion with `rake`, it completes with the tasks list from `rake -T`.

When I run a specific test, one of the parameters is the path to the test file:

```
rake test test/models/dummy_model.rb
```

I often try to autocomplete this path and it obviously do not work.

```
rake test test/models/...
```

I would like to be able to complete from file paths in addition to tasks. How could I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right, this only occurs, when you use the form `rake test ...`. Then you can use this patch against `$fpath/_rake`

```
diff --git a/Completion/Unix/Command/_rake b/Completion/Unix/Command/_rake
index 7fed949..96ee930 100644
--- a/Completion/Unix/Command/_rake
+++ b/Completion/Unix/Command/_rake
@@ -37,12 +37,16 @@ case "$state" in
   ;;
   target)
     local -a targets
-    targets=( ${${(f)"$(_call_program targets $words[1] -sT $opt_args[(I)(-N|--nosearch)] ${(kv)opt_args[(I)(-f|--rakefile)]} 2>/dev/null)"}/(#b)rake ([^ ]##) ##\# (*)/${${match[1]}//:/\\:}:${match[2]:l}} )
-    if (( ! ${targets[(I)rake aborted!]} )) then
-      _describe -t targets 'rake target' targets && ret=0
-    else
-      _message -e targets 'rake target'
-    fi
+    if [[ $words[$((CURRENT-1))] == "test" ]]; then
+       _files && ret=0
+       else
+           targets=( ${${(f)"$(_call_program targets $words[1] -sT $opt_args[(I)(-N|--nosearch)] ${(kv)opt_args[(I)(-f|--rakefile)]} 2>/dev/null)"}/(#b)rake ([^ ]##) ##\# (*)/${${match[1]}//:/\\:}:${match[2]:l}} )
+           if (( ! ${targets[(I)rake aborted!]} )) then
+             _describe -t targets 'rake target' targets && ret=0
+           else
+             _message -e targets 'rake target'
+           fi
+       fi
   ;;
 esac
```

That patch in principle adds the condition `if [[ $words[$((CURRENT-1))] == "test" ]];` which checks if the previous argument equals "test". And if so, files and directories are returned via the `_files` function instead of rake targets.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks you very much, it worked perfectly. For the record, on OS X Yosemite, the file path is `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.5/functions/_rake` (`/usr/share/zsh/5.0.2/functions/_rake` on OS X Mavericks)

Comment: This should be in the official completion file. Why you don't submit a patch??

Comment: Patches are not currently being accepted via the SourceForge ticketing tools. The shell is being maintained by various (entirely self-appointed) subscribers to the mailing list,

zsh-workers@zsh.org

so mail about any issues (bug reports, suggestions, complaints...) related to the development of the shell should be sent there. If you want someone to mail you directly, say so. Most patches to zsh appear there first.

Comment: @pablox Please feel free to submit this patch to zsh-workers. I haven't done it myself as I don't know `rake` and hence cannot judge if it only addresses a special case or make sense generally.

Comment: I'll continue using a couple of days more, but until now it seems okay :). How did you learn to make zsh completions?

Comment: @pablox: Unfortunately, I've never learned to write zsh completions and still can't write them from scratch. What I do is take one which is close to what I want and modify that.

Answer (score 2):

After years of frustration I created a new zsh rake autocomplete that you may find useful. Pretty simple, but it supports rake options, task names and files. Heavily commented since I'm not super familiar with zsh. https://gist.github.com/gurgeous/2aea9f096a7801215ff38cd031e17dd4